# Show that the Dirac-Delta distribution is a distribution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Let $0 \in U$. Define the distribution $\delta \in D'(U)$ as

$$\delta: \phi \rightarrow \phi(0)$$

Show that this really is a distribution. I'm struggling with the definition of a distribution.

Do I need to show that $\delta$ is a linear and continuous map and if so, how could I accomplish that in this case? There is another theorem that states that every integrable function can be seen as a distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should show that $\delta$ is a linear and continuous map. Linearity should be close to trivial.

For continuity one has that linear functional $u$ on $C^\infty_c$ is continuous, and thus a distribution, if for each compact set $K$ there exists a number $C_K>0$ and an integer $N_K\geq 0,$ such that for every test function $\phi$ with support on $K,$ one has
$$
|\langle \delta, \phi \rangle| \leq C_K \sum_{n\leq N_K} \|\phi^{(n)}\|_K,
$$
where $\|\psi\|_K = \sup_{x\in K} |\psi(x)|.$

Hint: For $\delta$ you can take $N_K=0$ and $C_K=1,$ so you only need to show that $|\langle \delta, \phi \rangle| \leq \|\phi\|.$

Comment: Thank you. Could you check if it would also be true to say that since $\phi_n \rightarrow_{D(U)} \phi \Rightarrow \delta (\phi_n) = \phi_n(0) \rightarrow_{D(U)} \phi(0) = \delta (\phi)$, $\delta$ is continuous.

Comment: @illuminatitruthseeker. Isn't that the definition of $\delta$ being (sequentially) continuous?

Comment: It is. Would this be sufficient to prove that $\delta$ is indeed continuous?

Comment: Sure. But you should explain why $\phi_n(0) \to \phi(0)$ when $\phi_n \to \phi$ in $D(U).$

Comment: Yes. But I'm not sure how to explain this.

Comment: Do you know what convergence in $D(U)$ means?

Comment: It means that there exists a compact subset (of the real numbers in this case) so that the support of $\phi$ is a subset of this subset and all derivatives in the real numbers have to converge uniformly.... But how could this help me?

Comment: Note first that it's enough to show that if $\phi_n \to 0$ in $D(U)$ then $\langle \delta, \phi_n \rangle \to 0.$ Therefore take $\phi_n \to 0$ in $D(U)$. Then $\|\phi_n\| \to 0$ by the definition of convergence in $D(U),$ so 
$$| \langle \delta, \phi_n \rangle | = | \phi_n(0) | \to 0.$$